# Newton's oscillating spring ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

So I have never taken differential equations and I was never even required to. However, I was given a second order ODE $$x^{"}+a(x^{'})^3+b(x^2-1)=0$$ Given $v=x^{'}$, I was then asked to rewrite it as a first order ODE of the form $(x,v)^{'}=F(x,v)$ and I got $$v^{'}+av^3+b(x^2-1)=0$$ but I have no idea if this is right.

Also, I was asked to find all the zeros of $F(x,v)$ and characterize these points which is also confusing to me.

Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Almost right.  You just have to rearrange it in the form you were asked for:

$$ \pmatrix{x\cr v\cr}' = \pmatrix{v\cr -av^3 - b(x^2-1)\cr} $$

Next: zeros of $F(x,v)$ means $x$ and $v$ so that $v = 0$ and $-av^3 - b(x^2-1) = 0$.  So you already know $v=0$; what must $x$ be?

Answer (score 1):

You get a system of 2 first order ODE

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& v \\
\frac{dv}{dt} &=& -av^3 - b(x^2 - 1)
\end{align}

or equivalently

$$
\frac{d{\bf y}}{dt} = {\bf F}({\bf y})
$$

with ${\bf y} = (x, v)$. The zeros are the points where ${\bf F}({\bf y}) = {\bf 0}$, which are simply

$$
v = 0 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ x = \pm 1
$$

Comment: Thanks a ton! Really helpful to see it presented like that!